# how to create a custom design website in salesfoce

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

I am very new in salesforce. One of my client needs to start a new website in salesforcer. I have gone through the document and google for the information, but the direct information is less about how to create a new custom design wesite in salesforce. I need to host the website in a separate domain. Please guide me over this, i am very confused on checking their document.

I can lot of option in salesforce to do the thing, like by using visual force code, using the site services and pages, using apex api. I need know what is the best method to develop a website in salesforce or what is the difference between each of these.

Answer (score 1):

For UI that runs outside of Salesforce (but can still integrate with Salesforce data, use Heroku (a part of Salesforce).  Check out [the Heroku getting started guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/start).

For UI that runs inside of Salesforce you can either use [Visualforce](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/visualforce_fundamentals), [Lightning Components](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/lex_dev_lc_basics), or [Canvas](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_connect.meta/platform_connect/canvas_framework_intro.htm).

Comment: I am not planning to develop in heroku, but thank you for your comment on this. We need to know an option for create the entire section using our html. Basically i am wordpress developer that's why i am thinking so. But i am confused with the documentation on site.com. I am actually stuck about where i need to start.

Comment: Do you want the custom UI embeded in the Salesforce UI?

Comment: Yes. Exactly. I want the same

Comment: okay somehow i can understand the some of the procedures we are following in salesforce. But let me know if we have complete HTML for our website, which is the best way to proceed with. I have all the pages with seperate HTML and css also i needs to update for the entire website. How can i start in that case?

Comment: Do those pages need to access Salesforce data?  If so, go with Canvas.  If not, create an empty Visualforce page and then iframe in the content.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check out - [Force.com Sites](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Sites)

Comment: I can see lot of option for developping the web application like by using visual force, using the site.com and using apes api. But i am confused about which way will be a better option, or can you tell which is the right way to do it. The force.com is not exactly giving the right document about to proceed this.

Comment: Hi Anoop, I feel you are not understanding what Salesforce.com is for. Guide me why you want to build a website using Salesforce.com?? Are you exposing Salesforce.com data to external world via the website you intent to build??